expressjs not sending response
I've done this 100 times, but I'm not sure what's going on in this instance... I send login creds from my page to an express server:
async function request(url, data) {
  data = JSON.stringify(data);
  
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: data,
  });
  console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response));
  return response.json();
}
    
$("#log-form").submit(async () => {
  const data = {
    username: $('input[name=log-user]').val(),
    password: $('input[name=log-pass]').val()
  };
  
  const result = await request("/login", data);
  console.log("log-result", JSON.stringify(result));
  if (result.status == "ok") {
    alert("You have successfully logged in!");
  } else {
    alert(result.error);
  }
  //window.location.href = "/chat";
});

The express server gets the data as it should, but never seems to send a response back to the page:
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  
  const errString = "Incorrect usernane/password combo.";
  
  let result = await query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE name = '"+username+"'");
  result = result[0];
  
  if (result.user_id) {
    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, result["password"]);
    console.log('validPass', valid);
    if (valid) {
      // login and set session
      data.status = "ok";
      data.data.user = result;
      
      //req.session.user = result;
    } else {
      // invalid password
      data.status = "error";
      data.error = errString;
    }
  } else {
    // invalid password
    data.status = "error";
    data.error = errString;
  }
  console.log('data', data);
  res.status(200).send(data);
});

The console.log('data', data); line prints what it should, but neither res.json(data) nor res.send(data) are working. I get nothing in the browser console except the original request. No response. What am I doing wrong?

You are not returning.add return res.status(200).json(data);

What is the exact error you are getting?

where did you define data on the server

@KrzysztofKrzeszewski no error at all.

@traynor data is defined above the block: const data = { status: 'error', data: {}, error: '' };

@Subha makes no difference if it is actually returned or not.

What you are getting in response?

@chaoskreator can't reproduce, it all looks fine to me.. I'd suspect there's an error with query, but apparently not, if it reaches log line, still, I'd suggest adding error handlers to query and bcrypt, and also use parametrized queries. you might also try returning some hardcoded response from the server, and if that works, maybe try hardcoding request on the client, to narrow down the problem

Just a security advice: Don't use unescaped arguments in a database queries. -- Your current handling at '"+username+"' allows data manipulation by anyone.

@Christopher I did have the placeholders, but thought for some crazy reason it might be screwing it up, but no.

If you submit '; DELETE FROM User; SELECT '1 as value for username, you could end up with an empty table. The string submitted by query() will be: SELECT * FROM User WHERE name = ''; DELETE FROM User; SELECT '1'. -- Another possibility is: ' OR password = '<hash> as username would grant access as an "unknown user" just by submitting a common password-hash. This is even possible with the config entry: multipleStatements set to false.

@Christopher i am aware. this was just for testing.

Changing the submit event fixed the issue:
$("#log-form").on("submit", async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();


It looks like the data object is not initialized before you use it. This can potentially lead to a reference error or, in your case, it might not be structured properly when attempting to send it back to the client. You should initialize data at the beginning of your route handler.
let data = {};  // Initialize the data object

This was not the issue. The data object was inititialized above the copy/pasted code.
